# How to use a platform driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi b+ and want to read the CPU temperature in a Linux kernel file through this driver, bcm2835_thermal.c https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/drivers/thermal/broadcom/bcm2835_thermal.c.

But I am struggling to understand how this driver works. 
Here are my questions:
What is the call chain in this driver code?
Should I call the probe function and the get_temp function in the Linux file where I want to get the temperature?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This driver is a Linux kernel module, as identified by `#include <linux/module.h>` in the beginning and the three `MODULE_*` lines at the end.

The `bcm2835_thermal_probe()` function is listed as the `.probe` element in the `static struct platform_driver` for this driver, so as far as I understand, the probe function is called automatically when the driver is loaded, to determine if the driver is applicable for the hardware, and to initialize the driver if it is. It registers the `bcm2835_thermal_get_temp` as the function that can

On line #221, there is a call to `thermal_zone_of_sensor_register()`, so I think the output of the probe should become available somewhere under `/sys/class/thermal`.
The registration function registers the driver's functions listed in `bcm2835_thermal_ops` (just one, `bcm2835_thermal_get_temp()` as the `bcm2835_thermal_ops.get_temp()` function) as callable through the thermal zone API.

The driver also has a `bcm2835_thermal_debugfs()` function, and it appears to create a `debugfs` directory named `bcm2835_thermal`. Assuming your kernel has `debugfs` enabled, you could do a

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

and if the driver module is loaded and it has successfully initialized, there should be a directory `/sys/kernel/debug/bcm2835_thermal/` and some files in it allowing you direct access to the registers of this sensor from userspace, should you need it.

In short, this driver hooks into existing thermal zone and debugfs APIs in the kernel, the device tree will provide polling interval information, and then the thermal zone subsystem will keep updating the temperature automatically.

If you need the temperature information in userspace code, you should find it in the above-mentioned sysfs directory.

If you need it in kernel code, I think you just need to track down the appropriate `struct thermal_zone_device` from the device tree and either read the current temperature from the appropriate sensor sub-element of the struct, or explicitly call its `get_temp()` function if you need absolute up-to-the-microsecond latest information. I might well be wrong here, as I am not really a kernel programmer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I should go check how to track down the thermal zone device for getting the latest information in kernel code. If doing so, does it mean that I won't need this driver anymore?

Comment: You'll need to have this driver loaded, to make the sensor available to the thermal zone subsystem. This driver just provides the piece of code that makes the subsystem aware of the sensor and actually reads the sensor, and the thermal zone subsystem will normally call it for you.